# Geofence iOS Crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, core-location

I am trying to implement geofencing into my app. I am working off a great tutorial by [Kevin McMahon](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/get-started-geofencing-ios).

My problem is that I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address= ...) every time I try to create the geofences.

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *placeID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *lats = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *longs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [responseObject count]; i++) {
        [placeID addObject:[[responseObject objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"id"]];
        [longs addObject:[[responseObject objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"long"]];
        [lats addObject:[[responseObject objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"lat"]];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *latDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:lats forKeys:placeID];
    NSMutableDictionary *longDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:longs forKeys:placeID];

    NSMutableArray *geofences = [[NSMutableArray array] init];

    for(int k = 0; k < [responseObject count]; k++) {
        CLRegion *geofence = [self mapDictionaryToRegionWithLat:latDict withLong:longDict usingID:[placeID objectAtIndex:k]];
        [geofences addObject:geofence];
    }

    [self initializeRegionMonitoring:geofences];
```

### Creating the CLRegion

```
    - (CLRegion*)mapDictionaryToRegionWithLat:(NSDictionary *)latDict withLong:(NSDictionary *)longDict usingID: (NSString *)placeStringID {

        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title %@", placeStringID];

        CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[latDict objectForKey:placeStringID] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[longDict objectForKey:placeStringID] doubleValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

        CLLocationDistance regionRadius = 10.0;

        return [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerCoordinate
                                                       radius:regionRadius
                                                   identifier:title];
    }
```

### Initializing the region monitor

```
    - (void) initializeRegionMonitoring:(NSArray*)geofences {
        if (locationManager == nil) {
            //[NSException raise:@"Location Manager Not Initialized" format:@"You must initialize location manager first."];
        }

        if(![CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable]) {
            //[self showAlertWithMessage:@"This app requires region monitoring features which are unavailable on this device."];
            return;
        }

        for(CLRegion *geofence in geofences) { //ERROR HAPPENS HERE AFTER 7 ITERATION
            [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:geofence];
            NSLog(@"geofence made here:\n\n%@\n\n",geofences);
        }
    }
```

The error seems to occur after the 7th iteration (b/c there are 7 geofences) of "for(CLRegion *geofence in geofences)" as my NSLog in "locationManager: manage didStartMonitoringForRegion: region" does not show up.

Comment: ...which line is the error on?

Comment: doh! sorry about that fixing now

Comment: so [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:geofence]; <-- this line?

Comment: See below. It was my stupid mistake. Bad memory management, nothing to do with Core Location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with geofencing, location or Core Location at all. I simply forgot to release these mutable arrays I initiated:

```
NSMutableDictionary *latDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:lats forKeys:placeID];
NSMutableDictionary *longDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:longs forKeys:placeID];
```

Just released those dicts at the end of the method and everything works!

Comment: Huh? Leaking memory doesn't cause segfault. Overreleasing it does. Did you mean, by accident, the opposite?